# Apache2 HPKP without HSTS

Tags: apache-2.2, security, ssl, web-server

Is there a way to use public key pinning without HTTP Strict Transport Security? Both protocols (http and https) are configured via a respective vhost

I need the HTTP connection for an old program, but want to make the other areas as safe as possible.

Thank you

Comment: Why do you think this doesn't work? They are independent headers and not related.

Answer (score 1):

You can use HTTP even though you send the HSTS header. HSTS is just sent over HTTPS. So if your client doesn't use SSL then you shouldn't see it.

Comment: I tested this configuration in the past, because I know that. But the software says no. Maybe it's trying https of a very bad way. I do not know. But thank you

Comment: At the moment the software is working. With vhosts for https and one for http and no hsts enabled also no hpkp. In the tests I enable both and it doesn't work anymore. Then I decided to disable only hpkp and it doesn't work. Then I decided to test the same as the current state and it works. So I'm really sure about that. If it isn't possible I can't change the configuration. It's not a big problem but hpkp is a nice to have.

Comment: Then it's probably best to leave hpkp out.

Comment: Not the best way, but perhaps the only one. To explore this, I asked the question.

Comment: It's very bad practice to deploy HSTS and also expect some clients to only connect via http and therefore not load the HSTS header.